# Can I Push Data Native To React To Native in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have crate one apps in `react native` for `Android`. I Want to call `.java file` at middle also transfer data. After again `.java file` to `.js file`. its possible. please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it. Here i am sharing few useful links for that.

[Communication between Android and React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-android.html)

[Communication between iOS and React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html)

And in case of receiving data from java to react native you need to use `callback`

```
@ReactMethod
public void generate(final Callback successCallback)
{
    successCallback.invoke(<parameter you need to pass back>);
}
```

and from React Native you need to call

```
AndroidModule.generate((<parameter passed from native module>) => {

})
```

Comment: can you give me sample demo for it. just push with single parameter,

Comment: I have done it in my live project, but if you will follow the link i have given and snippet, you will be able to do it easily.